# How to change / to be horizontal?

Tags: characters, fractions

I like to change a/b to be

```
a
- 
b
```

how to do that?

Comment: yes,I only can use / now.

Comment: See my answer below. But really, since you ask this very elementary question, I guess you do not have access to any form of documentation? You need to remedy that. LaTeX is too complex to use without documentation.

Comment: Or have a look at this one: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/

Answer (score 14):

`\frac{a}{b}`, in math mode of course.

Answer (score 7):

For fractions use `$\frac{a}{b}$`, like Harald Hanche-Olsen said. For inline-math I still like fractions that use `/` because a `\frac` is often too tall. Here is a definition for a nicer fraction that uses `/`:

```
\def\nicefrac#1#2{\leavevmode%
    \raise.5ex\hbox{\small #1}%
    \kern-.1em/\kern-.15em%
    \lower.25ex\hbox{\small #2}}
```

It is used like this:

```
\nicefrac{a}{b}
```

Comment: The `nicefrac` package, or the `units` package, also offer a  `\nicefrac` command.

Comment: The [xfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) package seems to be the better choice.

Comment: Is this kind of command can be used on MathJaX? Because I can't try success on Statistical Analysis board.

Comment: You can also use $\dfrac{a}{b}$ if you want a larger fraction in inline math mode.

Comment: @Peter: using `\dfrac` in inline math is not very good because it changes the space between lines and by default LaTeX uses smaller fractions in inline math just to avoid this.

Comment: @Spike: Good point. I normally don't have long paragraphs and find that `\dfrac` useful, but I should have included what you pointed out.